# Malloc memory not accessible outside while loop

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to write a wrapper to take some pre-defined standard input from a file. The program should  skip a line if there is a '#' in the beginning, else store all the elements except the first 2 elements in an array called factorList.
I am using malloc to dynamically allocate memory to this pointer. 
I am then trying to access this array outside the while loop I declared it in, but its causing an error.

```c
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int degree  = 100;
    int tempDegree;
    int num;
    int * factorList;
    FILE * primeFile = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(!primeFile)
    {
        printf("Could not open file containing prime table\n");
    }
    char store[100] = {0};
    char lineCheck = ' ';
    int primeCheck = fscanf(primeFile, "%s", store);

    while(primeCheck != EOF)
    {
        if(strcmp("#",store) == 0)
        {
            printf("Mark1\n");
            // Clearing Store array
            memset(store, 0 , sizeof(store));
            // Skip this line
            while((lineCheck != '\n') && (primeCheck != EOF))
            {
                primeCheck = fscanf(primeFile, "%c", &lineCheck);
            }

            lineCheck = ' ';
            // Reading the start of the next line
            if(primeCheck != EOF)
            {
                primeCheck = fscanf(primeFile, "%s", store);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tempDegree = atoi(store);
            if(tempDegree == degree)
            {
                printf("Mark2\n");
                // This is the list of primes
                primeCheck = fscanf(primeFile, "%d", &num);
                factorList = malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
                int i;
                for(i=0;i < num; i++)
                {
                    primeCheck = fscanf(primeFile, "%d", &factorList[i]);
                    printf("%d",factorList[i]);
                }
                break;
            }
            else
            {    
                printf("Mark3\n");
                // Clearing Store array
                memset(store, 0 , sizeof(store));
                // Skip this line
                while((lineCheck != '\n') && (primeCheck != EOF))
                {
                    primeCheck = fscanf(primeFile, "%c", &lineCheck);
                }
                lineCheck = ' ';
                // Reading the start of the next line
                if(primeCheck != EOF)
                {
                    primeCheck = fscanf(primeFile, "%s", store);
                }
            }
        }

        // Testing Access to factorList , getting error here.
        int i = factorList[0];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp("#",store) == 0` will check if the whole line is exactly `#` ... not just the first character. Use `store[0] == '#'` instead.

Comment: it is allocated only on one condition, in other cases, the list would be NULL, check for NULL before accessing it

Comment: Your loop is very complicated; instead of reading the first line before the loop and having every code path inside the loop read the start of the next line, you should read the start of the line at the start of the loop (and if there is an error, `break;` out).

Comment: @radar: The final line is a test to see whether I can access the array outside the while loop, I am providing the necessary input so that the array gets allocated, but I am not able to access it outside the loop.

Comment: This looks like a *stellar* time to fire up your debugger.

Comment: And what is the error you are getting? Also, you need to free the memory you have allocated once it's use is over.

Comment: a variable has 'scope'.  If the variable is defined within a while loop, then the scope of the variable is the code block within the while loop.   In this case, define the variable before the while loop

Comment: @CoolGuy: I am getting segmentation fault, but I don't think freeing the memory is a problem, for one thing its very less.

Comment: @user3629249 it *is* defined before the while-loop.

Comment: @user3629249: I am declaring the pointer outside the loop, but dynamically allocating the memory inside the while loop, the memory should persist outside the while loop.

Comment: @AkshayGupta The code you have posted outputs content as you're filling the factor list. Post your output up to, and *including*, the segfault, doing so in your question. The code you have here can, and if you're *lucky*, *will* fault if `tempDegree == degree` is *never true*, evidence of which will be a lack of any of the aforementioned fill-output because that code path is never taken, thereby leaving `factorList` an indeterminate pointer. *Post the output*, and ideally, an MCVE, including sample input that reproduces the issue stand-alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
    // Testing Access to factorList , getting error here.
    int i = factorList[0];
```

is not outside the while loop. It is at the bottom of the loop, so will be executed once for each iteration of the loop.

Inside the loop is a branch. The 'true' part of the branch, if a line containing only a single '#' is read, does not assign anything to factorList. So, if during the first iteration of the loop, a '#' is encountered, the program may crash, because you are de-referencing a pointer which has not had a value assigned to it, invoking undefined behavior.

Inside the false branch, there is another branch. The false part of that branch also does not assign anything to factorList either, so the same thing will happen if tempDegree == degree is not true on the first iteration.

There are quite a few other areas for improvement, I would pay close attention to some of the comments to your question.